# Unblock Mouse Move

Tags: c++, mouseevent, mouse, sendmessage, sendinput

I'm writing a program that simulates mouse movements for an application, but this program blocks mouse movement. Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Solutions I tried and results:

> ```
> SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
> SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
> ```
>
> There is no movement, but if the application is at the top, it sends a left click to the original position of the mouse.

> ```
> SetCursorPos(x,y);
> ```
>
> The mouse goes to the location I want, but then when I send a click it never accepts it until I manually move my mouse.

> ```
> SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
> ```
>
> The mouse does not provide any movement when the application is open, but it does not prevent clicks.

> ```
> INPUT mouseEvent;
> mouseEvent.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
> mouseEvent.mi.dx = x;
> mouseEvent.mi.dy = y;
> mouseEvent.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
> mouseEvent.mi.mouseData = 0;
> mouseEvent.mi.time = 0;
> mouseEvent.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
> SendInput(1, &mouseEvent, sizeof(INPUT));
> ZeroMemory(&mouseEvent, sizeof(INPUT));
> ```
>
> The mouse does not provide any movement when the application is open, but it does not prevent clicks.

Comment: If you send `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, it would be prudent to follow that up with a `WM_LBUTTONUP`.  Many programs trigger off the latter.  Also, a proper statement of what you're actually trying to achieve would be useful.  Currently, this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I know the requirement of WM_LBUTTONUP, I am already using it, I have already edited the topic.